# How to not repeat dropdown population after POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I work with sails.js and I was wondering if there is a better way to manage dropdown lists population after a form is submitted.

```
// app/api/controllers/UserController.js
module.exports = {
  form: (req, res) => {
    let cProfiles, cGroups;
    Profiles.find()
    .then(profiles => {
      cProfiles = profiles; 
      return Groups.find();
    })
    .then(groups => {
      cGroups = groups;
      return res.view('users/form', { cProfiles, cGroups }); // cProfiles and cGroups used to populate dropdown lists in the form
      })
    });
  },

  add : (req, res) => {
    req.checkBody({...}); // I use express-validator
    let errors = req.validationErrors();
    if ( errors ) {
      // manage errors
    }
    else {
      User.create({...}).then(user => res.redirect('/user'));
    }
  }
}
```

.

```
// app/config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
 ...
'get /user'     : 'UserController.form',
'post /user'    : 'UserController.add',
...
}
```

After the form is submitted, if there are errors, I want to show my form again, with all the fields populated and the errors.
Do I have to repeat all the find().then() things in the add function ?

Comment: Mmm. Do you want to return a message to user informing that he miss something?

Comment: Yes. Like "name is mandatory" or something. But I don't want to repeat my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Flash message:

In your server code you can use `req.flash()`:

```
form: (req, res) => {
  let errors = req.validationErrors();
  if ( errors ) {
    // manage errors
    req.flash('error', "MY_ERROR_MESSAGE");
  }
```

In your EJS you need to get flash messages inside your session. I have created a partial ejs like [this](https://github.com/makah/sails-rateSite/blob/master/views/partial/flash.ejs)

```
<% if (req.session.flash) {  %>
    <% if (req.session.flash.success) { %>
        <% for(var i=0; i<req.session.flash.success.length; i++) {%>
            <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">
                <%= req.session.flash.success[i] %>
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% req.session.flash.success = undefined %>
    <% } %>

    <% if (req.session.flash.warning) { %>
        <% for(var i=0; i<req.session.flash.warning.length; i++) {%>
           <div data-alert class="alert-box warning radius">
                <%= req.session.flash.warning[i] %>
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% req.session.flash.warning = undefined %>
    <% } %>

    <% if (req.session.flash.error) { %>
        <% for(var i=0; i<req.session.flash.error.length; i++) {%>
           <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius">
                <%= req.session.flash.error[i] %>
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% req.session.flash.error = undefined %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Finally in layout.ejs:

```
<body>    
  <%- partial('partial/flash') %>
  <%- body %>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: I already use flash but it requires to redirect before showing messages. And this is my problem. How to keep errors and user's entries after redirect ?

Comment: Mmmmm. You can use [validators](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) in client side, to prevent client to unnecessary wait for server to process something that the client can do

Answer (score 0):

I would go with validating on the client side personally. If you are requiring information to be mandatory then you can use very simple html validators.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp - Scroll down to view "Constraint Validation HTML Input Attributes"

This will clean up the bulk of your use cases and for anything more complex I would jump into using a client side library.

In short, stop the rubbish getting to your controller and model in the first place so attack it from the view validation. After that check critical parameters in your controller to protect the model, as you say this may well result in the usage of find() etc if you hit problems. Alternatively, you can capture the req.param inputs and push that data straight back into your redirect (or just do a res.view('page',dataitems)) route and handle the assignment to relevant controls via jquery or ejs templating.